# ExtractValue for multiple elements

Tags: extract-value

Need to get:

firstdatavalue

seconddatavalue

values from text
and dont know if using EXTRACTVALUE is best option

```
<TextblockParameter>

  <tagName>firstdata</tagName>

  <value>firstdatavalue</value>

</TextblockParameter>

<TextblockParameter>

  <tagName>seconddata</tagName>

  <value>seconddatavalue</value>

</TextblockParameter>
```

Comment: How is this related to the SQL language?

Comment: i am using sqldeveloper and need to get information from one of table